# Prevent xss attack on spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, xss

In my spring application I have some endpoints which are affected by xss vulnerability. I have been asked to fix this problem.
This is what I have done until now:

In web.xml I adedd as first:

```
<context-param>
<param-name>defaultHtmlEscape</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Secondly I added this filter:

```
 <filter>
   <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
     <javaee:param-name>encoding</javaee:param-name>
     <javaee:param-value>UTF-8</javaee:param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
     <javaee:param-name>forceEncoding</javaee:param-name>
     <javaee:param-value>true</javaee:param-value>
   </init-param>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

And then I addedd xssFilter:

```
 <filter> 
   <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.cj.xss.XSSFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping> 
   <filter-name>XSSFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

and copied the xssflt.jar in WEB-INF/lib.

Now I'm asking can be this enough and the correct way to prevent xss?
Unfortunatly we are using old version of spring-security (and we cannot update it cause this is a very legacy project) and we cannot implement CSP header. At the same time sanitize the user input is very hard for the nature of legacy code.
Can you tell me if this is the right path to follow in order to protect my spring (no boot) application?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO these should be enough. The best way to know is to test it. Testing XSS vulnerability is quite easy. You may refer this [link](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/01-Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_Site_Scripting). Please do make sure that you test the old application also to reproduce the issue and then verify that its fixed in the latest version.

Comment: But I need to implement any of that filter class, or just defining them into web.xml is enough?